# How subnetting works on network design?

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address

Maybe this question is very easy for some people. I know very basic of networking and I am trying to learn more. I have followed tutorials on Microsoft and I read this:

> Using a subnet mask of 255.255.255.192, your 192.168.123.0 network
>   then becomes the four networks 192.168.123.0, 192.168.123.64,
>   192.168.123.128 and 192.168.123.192. These four networks would have as valid host addresses:

```
   192.168.123.1-62
   192.168.123.65-126
   192.168.123.129-190
   192.168.123.193-254
```

But when I used online subnet calculator here I got available host adderss range of:

> 192.168.123.1 - 192.168.123.62

I appreciate if anyone can explain how can I access

```
   192.168.123.65-126
   192.168.123.129-190
   192.168.123.193-254
```

by subnet mask of 255.255.255.192, on 192.168.123.0 network or explain if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please review the answer About "Calculating Subnets" [here](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/775), which is quite relevant to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you have four different networks:
`192.168.123.0`
`192.168.123.64`
`192.168.123.128`
`192.168.123.192`

You need to put each of those as a separate network into your calculator.  Your calculator will only work on one network at a time, and you have four networks.

If you enter 192.168.123.192 as the network with a mask of 255.255.255.192, you should get 192.168.123.193 - 192.168.123.254 as host address range.

Comment: I got your idea but I think with 128 I get 192.168.123.129 - 192.168.123.190

Comment: Correct.  I had a misstatement there.  I was looking at the 192 on the mask when I was typing the hosts.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

With the four defined networks that you want to use:

```
192.168.123.0/26 (/26 = 255.255.255.192)
192.168.123.64/26
192.168.123.128/26
192.168.123.192/26
```

You apply these four networks onto router interfaces. Suppose you use the first address as your gateway address, your router interfaces would be assigned these addresses:

```
!
interface FastEthernet 0/0
 description network-1
 192.168.123.1 255.255.255.192
!
interface FastEthernet 0/1
 description network-2
 192.168.123.65 255.255.255.192
!
interface FastEthernet 0/2
 description network-3
 192.168.123.129 255.255.255.192
!
interface FastEthernet 0/3
 description network-4
 192.168.123.193 255.255.255.192
!
```

So with a computer on network-1, that computer can have an address of 192.168.123.2 with a default gateway of 192.168.123.1.

A computer on network-2, can have an address 192.168.123.68 with a default gateway of 192.168.123.65.

So on and so forth as long as the address meets the criteria of the range of the respective subnet.